# Why was Jakarta jsp log taglib retired?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I understand that jakarta taglibs were retired since most of the functionality was replaced by JSTL, however, why was the **Logs** taglib retired? Is there a better alternative to this straightforward taglib for logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that jakarta logging was retired because it's considered a bad thing to do logging within your view templates.

I'd recommend that you design your JSPs in a way that you don't require any logging inside. Put all the logic into the beans which are displayed, and do the logging there as well.

Comment: Why is logging from a view a bad thing? Despite the effort one goes through to eliminate scriptlets, conditional code and to express the view in a declarative form, rendering a view is still a series of events. Any arbitrary event might need to be logged.

Comment: By executing log statements from within your templates, you're mixing presentation logic and application logic. With any other templating language, you'd enable logging somewhere in the parser - but granted, I don't know how to do that for JSP rendering.